# Term to represent a parent that has children that no longer exist

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for useful terminology to represent case(es) where a parent is no longer able to access a child.  Let's say I have an object that at one point contained an array of child elements

```
    {
      id: 123,
      childIds: [1,2,3]
    }
```

Then, through whatever circumstances, the `child Id 2` that this object referenced was destroyed.  In this case, `id: 123` will no longer be able to retrieve id 2 because it simply no longer exists.

When a child loses its parent, it becomes an **orphan**.  Digging around, I see that there doesn't seem to be an effective term for a [parent that loses their child.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193291/what-do-we-call-parents-who-lose-their-child/193294#193294?newreg=89fe9b77eb5b461a8561a7c47af2ae77)

I like the explanation on [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/148166/352995):

- *Like the male (opposite) equivalent of "widow" is "widower", so should the logical opposite of "orphan" probably be "orphaner".*

However, for the moment I'm settling on **[bereaved](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dictionary#dobs=bereaved)**/**[bereft](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dictionary#dobs=bereft)** as "orphaner" just doesn't roll off the tongue.  I'd much rather call getBereft() than getParentsThatLostTheirChildren()

In the meantime, I'll continue wondering if there is a more appropriate *computer science-ey* term out there that my fellow programmers might be using.

Comment: Maybe https://english.stackexchange.com/ would be a better forum for this question since you're really looking for a word, and don't have a coding problem.

Comment: That's why I reference https://english.stackexchange.com/ in my question and tagged it with [terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminology) as I was hoping that there would be an applicable CS term.  I get that there is no actual word that represents this in the english language.  My goal was to see what term other programmers have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms `Parent` and `Child` only make sense when used in a relative manner, and are typically used to qualify relationships to other objects, such as `Nodes` in a tree. There are many commonly used terms to qualify relationships between nodes and properties of nodes in a tree. You have already mentioned, `Parent`, `Child`, `Orphan`. There are also:

- `Ancestor`, relation of a node to all of its ancestor nodes.
- `Descendant` or `Offspring`, relation of a node to all of its descendant nodes.
- `Sibling`, relation between nodes that have a common parent node.
- `Leaf`, a node that has no child.
- `Root`, a node with no parent.

And there are probably several others.

When writing get/set/is functions, these qualifiers are typically not use alone, but concatenated with the term `Node`, such as `GetAncestorNodes()`, `GetSiblingNodes()`, `GetLeafNodes()`, `IsLeafNode()`, etc. This is for maximum clarity, but when the context is clear, we often see `GetChildren()`, `GetDescendants()`, `GetLeaves()`, etc.

Comment: You are right, I'm generalizing in my example.  In my case, I have a linked list and there are cases where child nodes get wiped off the database, leaving their parent nodes in a state that can throw errors.

So, if I wanted to reference a case where a node has had its children destroyed, just as a descendent that lost its node has become an orphan, would it be clear and concise to say that the node would be considered **bereft/bereaved** or is there a better/more widely used term?

Comment: Ok, so it is not just a `leaf` node. You would like to capture the fact that it was once a `parent`, that it has become a `leaf` node, and that such nodes are causing error. I think something like `GetParentNodesWithoutChild()`, `GetMissingOffspringParentNodes()`, `GetInvalidParentNodes()`, etc. would describe the nodes you are after using commonly used node terminology. The last two examples would convey the idea that there is something wrong with these nodes. So, this might be even better.